# Asymptotes of $r \theta \cos \theta = a \cos 2\theta$

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry, polar-coordinates

Asymptotes are the lines which touch the curve at infinity.

Putting $u=\frac{1}{r}$, then

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
u &= \dfrac{\theta \cos \theta}{a \cos 2\theta} = F(\theta)\\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

When $r \rightarrow \infty$, $u \rightarrow 0$, or

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\dfrac{\theta \cos \theta}{a\cos 2 \theta} &= 0\\
\theta \cos \theta &= 0\\
\theta &= 0, \pm \dfrac{\pi}{2}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

**i.e.** when $r \rightarrow \infty$, $\theta \rightarrow 0, \pm \dfrac{\pi}{2}$. So,

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\theta_1 &= 0, \pm \dfrac{\pi}{2}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Differentiating $F(\theta)$ w.r.t $\theta$,

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
F'(\theta) &= \dfrac{a\cos 2 \theta \dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d\theta}} (\theta \cos \theta) - \theta \cos \theta \dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d\theta}} (a\cos 2\theta)}{a^2 \cos^2 2\theta}\\
F'(\theta) &= \dfrac{a\cos 2\theta (\cos \theta - \theta \sin \theta) + 2a\theta \cos \theta \sin 2 \theta}{a^2\cos^2 2 \theta}\\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

[image]

The equation of the asymptote in case of polar curves is given by,

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
r \sin (\theta - \theta_1) &= \dfrac{1}{F'(\theta_1)}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

So in our case, asymptotes are,
[image]

[Plotting](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/7txfwb8n1c) reveals that while first two are asymptotes, the third one does not seem to be.

My approach looks fine but why is this discrepancy between graph and my solution?

Answer (score 1):

<s>You miscalculated $F'\left(-\dfrac \pi 2\right)$. It is actually $\dfrac{-\pi}{2a}$. You will find it is the same line as for $\theta = \dfrac \pi 2$.</s>

These asymptotes are actually rays, not lines. $\dfrac \pi 2$ is the asymptote for the top side of the graph and $-\dfrac \pi 2$ is the asymptote for the bottom side of the graph.

However, there are more asymptotes that you missed. Each of those climbing curves has its own asymptote.

Comment: I rechecked with $-\frac{\pi}{2}$, still got the same. Isn't this right? 

\begin{align}
F'\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\right) &= \dfrac{a \cos(-\pi)(\cos\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\right) + \frac{\pi}{2} \sin(-\frac{\pi}{2})) + 0}{a^2}\\
&= \dfrac{-a(0-\frac{\pi}{2})}{a^2}\\
&= \frac{\pi}{2a}
\end{align}

Comment: You are correct. I apparently made a sign error, and thought you did (It did after all explain the graph). I marked off the erroneous part, but left the rest of the post alone, because it is still accurate: Each asymptote is only asymptotic in one direction (except when the opposite direction happens to correspond to another asymptote). So my remarks about what you should get are correct, but I was wrong about why. I am not familiar with the asymptote formula you are using, but I guess there is some error in how you are applying it. And my remark about more asymptotes is definitely correct.